# Why do red onions turn blue or green when cooking sometimes?

Tags: food-science, onions

I cooked a pot of beans with some red onions last night.  Today for lunch when I got them out of the fridge, all of the onions had turned a blue/green colour!

They still *taste* ok, but sure looks unappetizing!

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Which kind of beans did you use?

Comment: Great northern white beans.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The pigments that give onions the colour behave like a litmus test. They are red in the naturally acidic onion. They turn green/blue in an alkaline environment. It sounds like when you cooked the beans it created that alkaline environment to cause the colour change.

[See Here.](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2007/03/13/AR2007031300374.html)

Comment: Preparing your own indicator solution with red cabbage juice is a safe and fun little experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Cooked red onion does turn dark blue-green colour in the fridge, but when you warm it up it turns a reddish colour again.